# login feature php

Tags: php, session, cookies, authentication, session-cookies

I`m going to implement a login feature to a website that I`m building ... I have two options while implementing, cookies and sessions.

Which will be better to use for each of these scenarios?

Remember Me.
Sign In/Login.

Shall I use sessions or cookies? or both?

If both, how can I create, store and load cookies? And how can I add the cookies to the session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case that you mentioned, you certainly have to use both.

Session is needed for server side verification while cookies are needed storing information in the client side.

Here are the links for [Sessions](http://bd.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) and [Cookies](http://bd.php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) from PHP Site.

Comment: any tutorials for cookies and how to load them in the sessions?

Answer (score 3):

Session is used with login and this is the standard way to do the login thing.
Remember cookies and session both are different.

Of course session uses cookie to identify the session of current user.

and the remember me works on cookies save the userid and pass in cookies and implement remember me.

You can create cookies with php function [setcookie()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) and for your second question session create a cookie by itself and maintain the session id as cookie value so don't need to handle session cookie by yourself.

Comment: Can you elaborate with an example?

Comment: @sikas: This is very simple and there is good example in manual itself. use [session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php) when you are authenticating users see how session works and use cookies for remember me to save user name and password in cookies